# What’s the purpose of the `.WDESF_Store` file?

Tags: macos

While inspecting a folder on an external drive, I encountered an unusual file:

```
$ ls -ltr .*
-rw-r--r--  1 alexwlchan  staff     0 12 Oct  2014 .localized
-rw-r--r--@ 1 alexwlchan  staff     0 21 Mar  2015 .WDESF_Store
-rw-r--r--@ 1 alexwlchan  staff  6148  7 Aug 14:04 .DS_Store
```

I know what the `.localized` and `.DS_Store` files are for, but I’ve never seen a `WDESF_Store` file before. Nor does Google have anything – it points me to searches for `.DS_Store`.

The external disk has only been plugged in to one Mac since it was last formatted, which was in January 2015. It’s a 1TB partition of a 2TB drive, which is a Western Digital USB drive. The partition is damaged in some way: in particular, although it was originally read-write HFS+, it’s now read-only, and Disk Utility can’t repair it.

The Mac in question is running the latest version of El Capitan, although at the time this file was allegedly created, it was probably running a version of Yosemite.

Running `lsof` doesn’t show any process which seems to have this file open. This is the only file with such a name on my disk. So I’m a bit baffled as to why it’s there.

I don’t think I created this file myself – I can’t think of why I’d need to do so, but it’s long enough ago that it’s not impossible that I did, and have since forgotten. But the name similarity to `.DS_Store` makes me think it might be some weird bit of OS cruft.

**Does anybody recognise, or know the purpose of the .WDESF_Store file?**

Comment: What is the result of `xattr .WDESF_Store`?

Comment: @techraf Ooh, that looks suggestive: `com.apple.quarantine: 0002;54e657df;iA\x20Writer\x20Pro;`. iA Writer Pro is indeed an app that I’ve used, although not for a while.